# Three.js: What Is The Exact Difference Between Lambert and Phong?

Tags: graphics, 3d, three.js

I understand the difference between Lambert and Phong in general computer graphics. I also understand how we can change and create our own materials using three.js. But I cannot work out the difference between MeshLambertMaterial and MeshPhongMaterial in their default states.

I have tried switching them on a scene with one directional light source and 125 spheres, I cannot see any differences whatsoever. Three.js is being used in a chapter of my book and so I need to make sure all information is accurate and precise.

Thanks,
Shane

Comment: Use a rough polygonal mesh and a light source that leaves only a small bright highlight falling in the middle of a polygon and you should see a difference!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am assuming you want the exact difference between `MeshLambertMaterial` and `MeshPhongMaterial` as implemented in three.js.

You have to differentiate between the shading model and the illumination model. Three.js does not implement 'pure' Phong or Lambert models.

For `MeshLambertMaterial`, the illumination calculation is performed at each vertex, and the resulting color is interpolated across the face of the polygon. ( Gouraud shading; (generalized) Lambert illumination model )

For `MeshPhongMaterial`, vertex normals are interpolated across the surface of the polygon, and the illumination calculation is performed at each texel. ( Phong shading; (generalized) Phong illumination model )

You will see a clear difference when you have a pointLight that is close to a face -- especially if the light's attenuation distance is less than the distance to the face's vertices.

For both materials, in the case of `FlatShading`, the face normal replaces each vertex normal.

three.js.r.66

Answer (score 33):

Shane, it's not your fault that you're confused.

Lambert is an illumination model (with a physical basis) for the light reflected off a surface, expressed in terms of the incoming illumination's direction with respect to the surface normal at the point of incidence.

Phong is a more nuanced shading model (albeit a more hacky one) which says that light is composed of ambient + diffuse + specular components. It treats the ambient component as constant everywhere (hack!), the diffuse component using the Lambertian model above, and the specular component using a power-law falloff (which is a clever hack, roughly approximating actual BRDFs).

The word "Phong" is also an interpolation method (when used in the context of modern triangle-based rendering pipelines). When computing the illumination at a pixel in the interior of a triangle, you have two choices:

1. Gouraud shading: Compute the color at the three vertices and interpolate in the interior, using barycentric coordinates, or
2. Phong shading: Using the normal at the three vertices, interpolate the normal in the interior and compute the shading using this interpolated normal at each pixel.

This is why (as @RayToal pointed out), if your specular "highlight" falls in the interior of a triangle, none of the vertices will be bright, but Phong shading will interpolate the normal and there will be a bright spot in the interior of your rendered triangle.

Answer (score 3):

In computer graphics, it is very common to confuse **Phong reflection model** with **Phong shading**. While former is a model of local illumination of points like Lambertian, the later is an interpolation method like Gouraud shading. In case you find it hard to differentiate between them, here's a list of detailed articles on each of these topics.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_shading_algorithms

Answer (score 2):

If you know a little GLSL, I think the best thing for you to do is to look at the vertex/fragment shaders generated in both cases and look for the differences. You can use http://benvanik.github.com/WebGL-Inspector/ to get the code of the programs, or put a `console.log()` at the right place in three js sources (look for buildProgram, you should output `prefix_fragment + fragmentShader` and `prefix_vertex + vertexShader` to see the program code).

Also, you can have a look to the building blocks used to create both shaders:

Lambert: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLShaders.js#L2036
Phong: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLShaders.js#L2157

It may be more readable than to look at the source program code.