# three.js SpotLight acute beam not working

Tags: three.js, angle, lighting, spotlight

I am new to three.js but I have past experience from Unity with 3d objects and rendering,
I am having trouble with the SpotLight, I am trying to shed light from an imported obj, to make it seem like a working lamp.
I can't set the light's angle to an acute one because it just doesn't illuminate when it is beyond a certain value.

this is the relevant code for this:

```
const objLight = new THREE.SpotLight('yellow', 5);
objLight.angle = Math.PI/2;
objLight.penumbra = 0.1;
objLight.decay = 1;
objLight.distance = 40;
objLight.position.set(-0.48, 0.7, 0);
objLight.target.position.set(-0.9, 0, 0);
objLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(objLight);
scene.add(objLight.target);
```

this is how it looks like when the angle is set to

`Math.PI/2`: https://prnt.sc/vzddfy .
`Math.PI/3`: https://prnt.sc/vzdeel .
`Math.PI/4`: https://prnt.sc/vzdeks .

Now I moved the camera closer and I saw that the light is illuminating on the object but that's it: https://prnt.sc/vzder0 .

I tried playing with values for an hour and couldn't find a solution, I even tried removing the obj and the box and it didn't do anything.

I did find however, that if I move the light away from `x=-0.48` to `x=-4.48`, I can make it acute, up to Math.PI/6: https://prnt.sc/vzdgls

And if I want it to be more acute I need to move it further away.

My theory is that it has something to do with the distance to it's target or something, I tried to move the target away at one point but it didn't do anything.

Anyone knows what could be the issue?

The rest of the code:

```
 let renderer, camera, scene;

// const THREE = require('three');

function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();
// scene.background = new THREE.Color('red');

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 5;

new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight('white', 0.2);
scene.add(light);

const BoxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const BoxMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 'blue'});
const Box = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo, BoxMat);
Box.castShadow = true;
scene.add(Box);

const TopPlaneGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 1);
const TopPlaneMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 'white', side: THREE.DoubleSide});
const TopPlane = new THREE.Mesh(TopPlaneGeo, TopPlaneMat);
TopPlane.position.y = 5;
TopPlane.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
TopPlane.receiveShadow = true;

scene.add(TopPlane);

const BotPlaneGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 1);
const BotPlaneMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 'white', side: THREE.DoubleSide});
const BotPlane = new THREE.Mesh(BotPlaneGeo, BotPlaneMat);
BotPlane.position.y = -1;
BotPlane.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
BotPlane.receiveShadow = true;

scene.add(BotPlane);



const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

loader.load
(
    'objects/Lampe_FerBlanc.obj',
    function(obj) {
        obj.position.set(-0.40, 0.5, 0);
        obj.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
        scene.add(obj);
    }
)
    
const objLight = new THREE.SpotLight('yellow', 5);
objLight.angle = Math.PI/6;
objLight.penumbra = 0.1;
objLight.decay = 1;
objLight.distance = 40;
objLight.position.set(-4.48, 0.7, 0);
objLight.target.position.set(-0.9, 0, 0);
objLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(objLight);
scene.add(objLight.target);

const helper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(objLight);
helper.name = 'helper';
scene.add(helper);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

scene.getObjectByName('helper').update();

renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

init();
animate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're using `MeshLambertMaterial`, which calculates lighting on each vertex, instead of calculating on each face pixel. When the light hits a vertex (wide angle) it illuminates. But when the light only hits the face and doesn't touch a vertex (on narrower angles), the plane face doesn't show the light. Also, shining a yellow light on a blue box won't show anything due to the nature of light: `#ffff00 * #0000ff = #000000`.

Try changing to `MeshPhongMaterial`, and you'll see your lights and shadows being calculated more accurately. Run the code snippet below to see it in action.

```js
let renderer, camera, scene;
let objLight;
let objLightPos = 0;
let objLightAngle = 1;

// const THREE = require('three');

function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.z = 5;

new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight('white', 0.2);
scene.add(light);

const BoxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const BoxMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 'white'});
const Box = new THREE.Mesh(BoxGeo, BoxMat);
Box.castShadow = true;
scene.add(Box);

const TopPlaneGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 1);
const TopPlaneMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 'white', side: THREE.DoubleSide});
const TopPlane = new THREE.Mesh(TopPlaneGeo, TopPlaneMat);
TopPlane.position.y = 5;
TopPlane.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
TopPlane.receiveShadow = true;

scene.add(TopPlane);

const BotPlaneGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 1);
const BotPlaneMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 'white', side: THREE.DoubleSide});
const BotPlane = new THREE.Mesh(BotPlaneGeo, BotPlaneMat);
BotPlane.position.y = -1;
BotPlane.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
BotPlane.receiveShadow = true;

scene.add(BotPlane);
    
objLight = new THREE.SpotLight('yellow', 5);
objLight.angle = Math.PI/6;
objLight.penumbra = 0.1;
objLight.decay = 1;
objLight.distance = 40;
objLight.position.set(-0.48, 0.7, 0);
objLight.target.position.set(-0.9, 0, 0);
objLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(objLight);
scene.add(objLight.target);

const helper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(objLight);
helper.name = 'helper';
scene.add(helper);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

}

function animate() {
    objLightPos += 0.01;
    objLightAngle += 0.03;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    objLight.position.set(Math.sin(objLightPos), 3, 0);
    objLight.angle = Math.sin(objLightAngle) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    scene.getObjectByName('helper').update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801971/three-js-what-is-the-exact-difference-between-lambert-and-phong/15809154#15809154.

Comment: That was it! the material itself, now it works perfectly! thank you for your help and the additional information.